# Why does my R Markdown custom block work when knitting but not when using build book?

Tags: css, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm trying to incorporate custom blocks as documented in the R Markdown Cookbook ([Section 9.6](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html)). The code I am using is:

```
    ::: {.blackbox data-latex=""}
    Thank you for noticing this **new notice**! Your noticing it has
    been noted, and _will be reported to the authorities_!
    :::
```

The style.css file includes:

```
    .blackbox {
      padding: 1em;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

And the preamble.tex file includes:

```
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    
    \newtcolorbox{blackbox}{
      colback=black,
      colframe=orange,
      coltext=white,
      boxsep=5pt,
      arc=4pt}
```

as in the Cookbook example. However, when I 'build book', the box doesn't appear in the html output, only in the pdf. When I 'knit', the box does appear in the html output. Is this an issue with 'build book'?

EDIT:

I tried embedding the css directly into the rmd file in a chunk, e.g.:

````
    ```{css, echo=FALSE}
    black {
      padding: 1em;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }```
    
    <black> 
    Warning 
    \[E=mc^2\]
    </black>
````

There are 2 issues with this approach:

1. Without the equation, that works fine for html, but it can't handle the equation - it doesn't display the equation and the box gets split in two over two lines.
2. I'm not sure how to make it work for pdf output too? How do I tell tex to use the `newtcolorbox` I define in preamble.tex?

Comment: You can apply css files directly embedding them into an Rmd file via chunks. See the [relevant section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html#:~:text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20can%20use%20a%20css%20code%20chunk%20to%20embed%20the%20CSS%20rules%20directly%20in%20your%20Rmd%20document) of *R Markdown Cookbook*. Does this functionality help?

Comment: Hi @CarlosLuisRivera, I've tried that but there are a couple of issues (see edited post). It's not able to handle equations in html when I embed the css directly into the rmd file in a chunk. I'm also unsure of how I would make it work for latex in this example.

Comment: I don't think that `}\`\`\`` is valid for the css chunk. You should insert a line break between `}` and the last `\`\`\``.

Comment: For your second issue, have you tried to [fill `in_header` field in YAML section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-preamble.html)? I think you ought to share your full minimal working example including YAML section.